# Counting the Number of Outputs in a Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, count

Hopefully this is an easy one. I have trawled through the forums and Google, but have not found a solution.

**NOTE:** I have answered the problem, but was hoping their might be a way to do this within Python.

**Problem:** I want to count the number of different iterations (combinations) within a for loop. I have done this, and enumerate does help, but it restarts as the new combination starts. The long way around this was saving the list to a CSV and counting the combinations in Excel (which isn't bad) but I was hoping there was a way to return this number in Python.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

stuff = ['imp1', 'imp2', 'imp3','imp4', 'click1', 'click2', 'click3', 'click4']

results = []

for combination in range(0, len(stuff) + 1):
    for subset in enumerate(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(stuff, combination)):
        results.append(subset)

with open('Combinations_1.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(results)
```

In short, this gives me what I need, but I was wondering if there was a "value_counts" type function (similar to whats used in Pandas) to count the number of different unique combinations or permutations.

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Why don't you use a simple counter in your for loop? It should be updated after each: `results.append(subset)`. For example `count += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a counter variable and put it inside your for loop:

```
ls = []
count = 0
for element in enumerate(range(10)):
    ls.append(element)
    count += 1

print count

10
```

Implementing in your code

```
results = []
count = 0

for combination in range(0, len(stuff) + 1):
    for subset in enumerate(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(stuff, 
    combination)):
        results.append(subset)
        count += 1
```

Comment: Both of these work perfectly. Thank you. Knew it would be something simple that I hadn't of thought of! Appreciate you helping me.